# XPCOM over Firebreath Plugin whats the difference

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, firebreath

i had a recent start of a plugin development using XPCOM for Firefox but the have stopped supporting the COM object. that leaves me to just [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org). What i was looking for with the COM object was to record the Screen i.e. `a screen cast plugin.` I am not aware of the Power of Firebreath plugins and also to consider browsers restrictions and security, is it possible to make such a plugin to work with browser to record the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between XPCOM and npruntime (which FireBreath uses) is how the javascript methods and properties work.  Anything that could be done with XPCOM as far as system apis, etc, will still work in a npruntime plugin, whether created with FireBreath or not.

Comment: Is XPCOM still supported in Browsers(Firefox) with the Gecko SDK to start with. What do you recommend for developing, What would be the pros and cons by going either way?

Comment: XPCOM is not supported by any modern browsers as part of NPAPI, though it might be possible to use parts of it from a c++ firefox extension. I would use FireBreath to create any plugin, but then I wrote it so I'm perhaps not neutral on the question